# Weekdays for regression in R

Tags: r, regression

I'd like to use the days of the week as one of the predictive variables for a multivariate regression. However, I'm struggling on how to make R recognize the weekdays as categories or factors (or whatever it is that they need to be converted to). I've tried using dummy variables and the "factor" function, but haven't had any luck.

My data set has columns: total,var1,var2,var3,weekday

I'd like to have a lm(total~var1+var2+var3+weekday) so that I can use weekday as part of the predictive functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: Just `factor(weekday)` should do it. R will take care of all the dummy coding etc internally when you run `lm()`

Comment: It would help to see some data, the code you used and the precise problem (_e.g._ an error message).

Comment: factor(weekday) worked. I must've been not doing something correctly originially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newvariable<-factor(variable)
```

This renames the original variable as a factor.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.